# What is the file extension for SQLite code?

Tags: sql, sqlite, file-extension

In my JS+SQLite project, I'm putting database and table creation SQL code in a separate file, to make the structure clear. What is the recommended file extension? `.sql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a litte stupid for saying "yes, you got it!", but that is what it is.

The `.sql`-extension is used by some bigger Apps that process Databases, like SQirL and Eclipse IDE.

Keep in mind, that File extensions are purely meant to make it easier for the user to identify its content.
So basically, any extension that you deem readable is just as fine as the any other.